# PHPUnit Code Coverage Filter Ignored in Sonar?

Tags: ant, phpunit, sonarqube

I am using Sonar to view reports about our PHP project. It has worked out great so far but I have run into a snag. The code coverage seems to ignore filtered files.

My Ant configuration takes all the Solar PHP Plugin's modules and puts them into "analyzeOnly" mode to just parse the output of the modules (Of which I have broken out into separate build targets in ant). This is working out well, the path output as the Sonar PHP Plugin runs in the console seems to match all of my build logs. Everything seems to be ingesting and parsing okay except for the PHPUnit code coverage, the sonar.phpUnit.coverageReportFile. I believe I have my PHPUnit config setup correctly. When I view the HTML output for the code coverage, only the filtered files are in the report, yielding 80% code coverage. When I use Sonar to analyze the clover style xml output (this file contains only the correctly scanned files), Sonar shows only 17% code coverage. This is because it is saying all of my ignored files have 0% coverage. These are ignored for a reason, some of them are config type arrays (Zend Framework 2) and others are my test cases themselves.

I have done some background research and some answers seem to lead to a bug from over 2 years ago that was closed. This is on the current 3.4.1 version of Sonar with the latest PHP Plugin. Any ideas? Do I need to exclude the files somewhere else?

Ant Settings:`

```
<property name="sonar.phpUnit.analyzeOnly" value="true"/>
<property name="sonar.phpUnit.reportFileName" value="../../../build/logs/junit.xml"/>
<property name="sonar.phpUnit.coverage.analyzeOnly" value="true" />
<property name="sonar.phpUnit.coverageReportFile" value="../../../build/logs/clover.xml" />`
```

EDIT: This may have something to do with: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARPLUGINS-1394
The ignored files aren't checked by PHPUnit, so they aren't included in the report. Every file PHPUnit scans, it reports on. If the file has no coverage, it will report that the file has no coverage.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this problem?